# Bin numeric variables into factors, by using equal frequency binning in R. Be sure to give a label to each bin

Tags: r, data-manipulation

For any numeric variables in your data, bin them into factors. Bin them using equal frequency binning. Be sure to give a label to each bin. The dataset is Chile from package `CarData`. I need to bin this numeric variable "statusquo".

```r
Chile2 <- carData::Chile
Chile2$statusquo_bin <- cut(Chile2$statusquo,
                            breaks = 4,
                            labels = c("low","medium","high","very high"),
                            include.lowest = TRUE,
                            right = TRUE)
```

This is my code, and it is not right. Can someone help me to solve this problem?